# I need to change a zip code into a series of dots and dashes (a barcode), but I can't figure out how

Tags: python

Here's what I've got so far:

```
def encodeFive(zip):

    zero =  "||:::"

    one =   ":::||"

    two =   "::|:|"

    three = "::||:"

    four =  ":|::|"

    five =  ":|:|:"

    six =   ":||::"

    seven = "|:::|"

    eight = "|::|:"

    nine =  "|:|::"

    codeList = [zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]

    allCodes = zero+one+two+three+four+five+six+seven+eight+nine

    code = ""
    digits = str(zip)
    for i in digits:

        code = code + i    

    return code
```

With this I'll get the original zip code in a string, but none of the numbers are encoded into the barcode. I've figured out how to encode one number, but it wont work the same way with five numbers.

Comment: Have you considered simply using one of the available barcode fonts instead?

Answer (score 4):

```
codeList = ["||:::", ":::||", "::|:|", "::||:", ":|::|",
    ":|:|:", ":||::", "|:::|", "|::|:", "|:|::" ]
barcode = "".join(codeList[int(digit)] for digit in str(zipcode))
```

Comment: An additional note: zip is a built in python method, it's preferable to use another variable name.

Comment: Fixed.  I use `zip()` so rarely (list comprehensions or generators usually fit better), I forget it exists sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use a dictionary:

```
barcode = {'0':"||:::",
           '1':":::||",
           '2':"::|:|",
           '3':"::||:",
           '4':":|::|",
           '5':":|:|:",
           '6':":||::",
           '7':"|:::|",
           '8':"|::|:",
           '9':"|:|::",
           }

def encodeFive(zipcode):
    return ''.join(barcode[n] for n in str(zipcode))

print(encodeFive(72353))
# |:::|::|:|::||::|:|:::||:
```

PS. It is better not to name a variable `zip`, since doing so overrides the [builtin function `zip`.](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) And similarly, it is better to avoid naming a variable `code`, since [`code` is a module](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html#module-code) in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You're just adding `i` (the character in `digits`) to the string where I think you want to be adding `codeList[int(i)]`.

The code would probably be much simpler by just using a dict for lookups.

Comment: that should be `codeList[int(i)]`, as `i` is a string in this current example.

Comment: You're right! I didn't think of using int(i). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to use split() to create lists of strings:

```
codes = "||::: :::|| ::|:| ::||: :|::| :|:|: :||:: |:::| |::|: |:|::".split()

def zipencode(numstr): 
    return ''.join(codes[int(x)] for x in str(numstr))

print zipencode("32345")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you are usingm so I made an example in C#:

```
int zip = 72353;

string[] codeList = {
  "||:::", ":::||", "::|:|", "::||:", ":|::|",
  ":|:|:", ":||::", "|:::|", "|::|:", "|:|::"
};
string code = String.Empty;
while (zip > 0) {
  code = codeList[zip % 10] + code;
  zip /= 10;
}
return code;
```

Note: Instead of converting the zip code to a string, and the convert each character back to a number, I calculated the digits numerically.

Just for fun, here's a one-liner:

```
return String.Concat(zip.ToString().Select(c => "||::::::||::|:|::||::|::|:|:|::||::|:::||::|:|:|::".Substring(((c-'0') % 10) * 5, 5)).ToArray());
```

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: The tag wasn't there when I answered the question.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't check the revision history to see what was corrected, but in any case, I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is made in python.

```
number = ["||:::",
    ":::||",
    "::|:|",
    "::||:",
    ":|::|",
    ":|:|:",
    ":||::",
    "|:::|",
    "|::|:",
    "|:|::"
    ]
def encode(num):
    return ''.join(map(lambda x: number[int(x)], str(num)))

print encode(32345)
```

Comment: While your code is correct, a dictionary (with "0", "1"… as keys) seems more preferable.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ at the beggining i did a dict, but in order to make the example clearer i decided to use an "array".

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to generate a "postnet" barcode.  Note that the five-digit ZIP postnet barcodes were obsoleted by ZIP+4 postnet barcodes, which were obsoleted by ZIP+4+2 delivery point postnet barcodes, all of which are supposed to include a checksum digit and leading and ending framing bars.  In any case, all of those forms are being obsoleted by the new "intelligent mail" 4-state barcodes, which require a lot of computational code to generate and no longer rely on straight digit-to-bars mappings.  Search USPS.COM for more details.